# OSGi bnd gradle non-workspace demo or template

Tags: java, gradle, osgi, demo, bnd

Looking for a non-workspace #OSGi #bnd #gradle project sample/demo/template.

Anyone can share some insight into how to get the setup working?

I am not using eclipse, just plain gradle/java.
ideally with Apache Felix 
BND ver 4.x will be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you look at some of the Bnd Gradle plugin test cases? For example: https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/tree/master/biz.aQute.bnd.gradle/testresources/builderplugin1

Comment: thanks @BJHargrave. WIll try and combine all separate examples into one demo.